# Execute same query twice, but with single different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Excuse the simplicity of my question, I'm having a brain-fart:

Here's my table schema:

```
Foo( FooId, BarDate dateTime, Baz int )
```

Given this query

```
SELECT
    MAX( Foo.BarData )
FROM
    Foo
WHERE
    Foo.Baz = 2
    AND
    Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
```

There are cases where this query returns `NULL` because there are no rows that meet the criteria, in those situations I want the query to return the same value, except where `Foo.Baz = 0`.

I could do it with two subqueries, but it seems a hack. Isn't there a better way?

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( Attempt1.BarData, Attempt2.BarData )
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX( Foo.BarData ) As BarData
        FROM
            Foo
        WHERE
            Foo.Baz = 2
            AND
            Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
    ) As Attempt1
    OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX( Foo.BarData ) As BarData
        FROM
            Foo
        WHERE
            Foo.Baz = 0
            AND
            Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
    ) As Attempt2 ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Just select both rows and limit result to 1 row, order so preferred row was first

```
SELECT TOP 1
  MAX( Foo.BarData )
FROM
  Foo
WHERE
  ((Foo.Baz = 2) OR
  (Foo.Baz = 0))
AND
  Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
GROUP BY Foo.Baz
ORDER BY Foo.Baz DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean by top max, maybe you have missed GROUP BY, ORDER BY

Comment: No it will return 1, you are not taking GROUP BY into consideration

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get the `MAX` values for both Foo.Baz in the same query, using a `CASE` to separate the raw data

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Foo.Baz = 2 THEN Foo.BarDate ELSE NULL END)
              , MAX(CASE WHEN Foo.Baz = 0 THEN Foo.BarDate ELSE NULL END)
               )
FROM   Foo
WHERE  Foo.Baz IN (0,2)
  AND  Foo.BarDate < @dateParameter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(    
    (SELECT MAX(Foo.BarData) FROM Foo WHERE Foo.Baz = 2 AND Foo.BarData < @dateParameter),
    (SELECT MAX(Foo.BarData) FROM Foo WHERE Foo.Baz = 0 AND Foo.BarData < @dateParameter)
)
```

Depending on your platform it's possible this has a better plan than other answers. On SQL Server you don't need a FROM clause. On Oracle you could select from DUAL. Other systems might need a dummy expression that returns a single row instead.

OP's query could have just been written with a cross join rather than the outer join. That might be part of the reason it feels like a hack. I'd say that your requirement isn't really a normal sql-esque question so any answer will seem that way.

If you want to emphasize that the typical path is the Foo.Baz = 2 case you might like the way this looks:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    MAX(Foo.BarData),
    (SELECT MAX(Foo.BarData) FROM Foo WHERE Foo.Baz = 0 AND Foo.BarData < @dateParameter)
)
FROM Foo
WHERE Foo.Baz = 2 AND Foo.BarData < @dateParameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the list,you may use IF..ELSE too as given below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Foo WHERE Foo.Baz = 2)
BEGIN
SELECT  MAX( Foo.BarData)
FROM    Foo
WHERE   Foo.Baz = 2
AND     Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT  MAX( Foo.BarData)
FROM    Foo
WHERE   Foo.Baz = 0
AND     Foo.BarData < @dateParameter
END
```

In case if it helps you.